# Default action animations for navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm looking for a way to declare a default animation for the actions from a fragment using [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/). Maybe there is not an implementation to achieve this behavior yet?

Here the code that I want to remove duplicate code:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/launcher_home">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/launcher_home"
        android:name="fr.ylly.sgb.gyproc.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_our_solutions"
            app:destination="@id/ourSolutionsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_study_cases"
            app:destination="@id/studyCasesFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_aboutUs"
            app:destination="@id/aboutUsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
    </fragment>
```

Comment: I can't test this right now but my idea was to use an extra layout file for the default action and then to specify/overwrite the necessary attributes(id, destination) when adding the action by using an <include> tag. Did you try something like that?

Comment: Didn't think on that, anyway I get a `Element include is not allowed here` :/

Comment: Well, it was worth a try ( from the docs it looked like my current AS version is too old so I couldn't find out quickly). I also didn't find any way of setting all of it up programmatically, so no luck there :(